# Inputting an array from Address functions into a WEIBULL function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I am using a Weibull distribution with an Array formula.

When I enter:

```
=SUM(WEIBULL.DIST($A6-EUPOM!$A$5:$A5+0.5,ShapeScale!$C$2:$C2,ShapeScale!$J$2:$J2,FALSE)*EUPOM!C$5:C5)
```

There is no problem, and the formula works well. However, when I replace the alpha or beta values with a formula which returns the same result (say `ShapeScale!$C$2:$C2`), I get a `#VALUE` error.

An example of the full code is:

> =SUM(WEIBULL.DIST($A7-EUPOM!$A$5:$A5+0.5,INDIRECT("ShapeScale!"&ADDRESS(2,MATCH(C$2,scaleprod,0))&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(C2),MATCH(C$2,scaleprod,0))),INDIRECT("ShapeScale!"&ADDRESS(2,MATCH(C$2,scaleprod,0)+7)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(C2),MATCH(C$2,scaleprod,0)+7)),FALSE)*EUPOM!C$5:C6)

I have even tried putting the alpha and beta formulas in a separate cell:`"ShapeScale!"&ADDRESS(2,MATCH(C$2,scaleprod,0))&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(C2),MATCH(C$2,scaleprod,0))` - then by using `INDIRECT`  - This works perfectly. But as soon as I combine them into one formula it errors.

To note, I am working on Mac Office.

Happy to share more information as needed.

Comment: I'm guessing you should use `INDEX` instead of `INDIRECT/ADDRESS`.

Comment: Thanks! That sorted it perfectly